Matrix kernel from perturbed matrix kernel.
Suppose I have matrix $A$ with kernel $ker(A)$. And I have a matrix $A'$ that is a perturbed matrix $A$. For the matrix $A'$ kernel $ker(A')$ exists. Is there an algorithm to find matrix $B$ such that $ker(A') = ker(A)\cdot B$?

What does $\ker(A') = \ker(A)\cdot \vec{u}$ mean?  The left hand side is a subset of $\mathbb F^n$ and the RHS a set of scalars.

Thanks, I fixed. Seems like now I need to muliply inverse kernel of perturbed matrix on kernel of clear matrix...
